# Is there a way to access the designation menu in the Steam version of Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-premium

In older versions you could press `d` to access the menu, however in the Steam version `d` just scrolls to the right.

Answer (score 2):

It's no longer a single dedicated menu. The commands that were available under designation are available on the bottom bar:

- Digging: "Setting digging orders (`m`)" will open a sub-menu containing regular digging, stairwells, channels, ramps, and Remove Construction
- Chopping trees: Available directly on the menu; hotkey is `l`.
- Plant gathering: Available directly, `g`
- Smoothing and engraving (`v`): Submenu includes smoothing, engraving, mine carts, and fortifications.
- The last button is to remove designations (`x`).
- Traffic settings are on the far-right of the buttons, hotkey is `T`

All of these buttons, except remove designation, have advanced options for setting the priority.